# Not changing values of form reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react-form

I have a form in which I am generating form fields dynamically . Now Issue is fields which are not dynamically generated are getting input and those field which are dynamically generated are not taking input in fields.   `name='name'`  and `name='age'`  fields are not getting input I cant insert data in them . while first two fields owner and description are working fine

```
import React from "react";
class Form extends React.Component {

  state = {
    cats: [{ name: "", age: "" }],
    owner: "",
    description: ""
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    alert('inot');
    if (["name", "age"].includes(e.target.className)) {
      let cats = [...this.state.cats];
      cats[e.target.dataset.id][
        e.target.className
      ] = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
      this.setState({ cats }, () => console.log(this.state.cats));
    } else {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.toUpperCase() });
    }
  };
  addCat = e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cats: [...prevState.cats, { name: "", age: "" }]
    }));
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  handleClick = e => document.getElementById(e.target.id).remove();

  // changeOption =(e) => {
  //   this.setState.cats(e.target.value);
  // }


  render() {
    let { owner, description, cats } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <div className='row mt-5'>
          <div className='col-md-12 mb-5'>
            <h3 className='text-center text-primary'>Create Products Option</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'></div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
            <label htmlFor='name'>
              <b>Owner</b>
            </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              name='owner'
              id='owner'
              value={owner}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
            <label htmlFor='description'>
              <b>Description</b>
            </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              name='description'
              id='description'
              value={description}
            />
            <button
              className='btn btn-success rounded-0 w-25 float-right mt-2 shadow-none'
              onClick={this.addCat}
            >
              +
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'></div>
        </div>

        {cats.map((val, idx) => {
          let catId = `cat-${idx}`,
            ageId = `age-${idx}`;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <div id={ageId} key={idx}>
              <div className='row mt-5'>
                <div className='col-md-3'></div>
                <div className='col-md-3'>
                  <label htmlFor={catId}>
                    <b>{`Cat #${idx + 1}`}</b>
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    name='name'
                    data-id={idx}
                    id={catId}
                    value={cats[idx].name}
                    className='name form-control'
                  />


                </div>
                <div className='col-md-3'>
                  <label htmlFor={ageId}>
                    <b>Age</b>
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    name='age'
                    data-id={idx}
                    id={ageId}
                    value={cats[idx].age}
                    className='age form-control'
                  />
                  <button
                    className='btn btn-success rounded-0 w-25 float-right mt-2 shadow-none'
                    onClick={this.addCat}
                  >
                    +
                  </button>
                  <input
                    type='button'
                    name={ageId}
                    data-id={idx}
                    id={ageId}
                    value={"-"}
                    className='age float-right mt-2 mr-3 btn btn-danger w-25 rounded-0 w-25 shadow-none'
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  />

                </div>
                <div className='col-md-3'></div>
              </div>

            </div>
            </form>
          );
        })}
        <div className='row mt-3'>
          <div className='col-md-3'></div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
            <label htmlFor='name'>
              <b>Min Selection</b>
            </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              name='min'
              id='min'
              value={""}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
            <label htmlFor='description'>
              <b>Max Selection</b>
            </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              name='max'
              id='max'
              value={""}
            />
            <input
              className='float-right btn btn-success mt-3'
              type='submit'
              value='Submit'
            />
            {/* <button className="float-right" onClick={this.addCat}>Add new cat</button> */}
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-keller-6v46p). Looks like you should be seeing some errors in your console that might provide some explanation:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

---

## Detailed answer

[Working Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-keller-6v46p). There are a few things wrong here:

#### Your `handleChange` function needs to change

Your function is looking at `className` which won't work. Your inputs return `form-control name` for example. Instead try using the element's `name`.

Updated function:

```js
  handleChange = e => {
    if (["name", "age"].includes(e.target.name)) {
      let cats = [...this.state.cats];
      cats[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
      this.setState({ cats }, () => console.log(this.state.cats));
    } else {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.toUpperCase() });
    }
  };
```

---

### Aside

**Do not render `<form>` elements in other `<form>` elements.**
Don't do this. You don't need another form here. Just remove that.

```
// Line 76-80:
        {cats.map((val, idx) => {
          let catId = `cat-${idx}`,
            ageId = `age-${idx}`;
          return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleChange}>
// ...
```

Comment: what should I write in onChange? can you please give some example ?

Comment: @gamer I've updated my answer with a detailed answer as well as a link to a working Codesandbox

Comment: thanks for for your reply @Martin . actually I have to submitt data for 1 category per form. So if user generate 10 forms he will submit 10 categories. For It I need to generate new forms.

Comment: You cannot have nested forms, [per spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element): "Content model: Flow content, but with no form element descendants." Regardless, that's not really the point of the question. Your question is specifically about controlling form fields - so I edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @gamer I've edited my answer now so that it is more specific to your question. If you've found that this solution works (specifically for controlling form inputs), feel free to mark the answer as correct.